# android Handler.postDelayed use in many places

Tags: android, android-handler

I have an app, which shows a video. At some point I want to give information about videos places. For example, historical places names. I am using this code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

But when I use this `postDelayed` comment in many times some message not show or overtake. What is the best solution to show some texts in a delay? For example 5 seconds later show A text, 15 sec later show B text, 30 sec later show C text. my codes look like this:

```
        switch ()

        case 1:
        openVideo(video1)

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //my message
          }
        }, 4000);

break;
        case 2:

        openVideo(video2)

        final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //my second message
          }
        }, 3000);


        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            //my third message
          }
        }, 15000);

break;
```

Comment: you can use a timer

Comment: Handler.postDelayed() is the correct way to do this. You probably have something else wrong with your code.

Comment: do you want this code to run again and again in seperated manner

Comment: @Mr.Popular, I ve added my codes look up

Answer (score 2):

Use multi-runnable.. Increase your duration for each text.

```
int mDuration=0,mAnimationDuration=5000;


mDuration=mDuration+mAnimationDuration;

//it called after 5 seconds
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
   //Your first text
 }
}, mDuration);

mDuration=mDuration+mAnimationDuration;

//it called after 10 seconds
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 //Your second text
}
}, mDuration);

mDuration=mDuration+mAnimationDuration;

//it called after 15 seconds
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
  //Your third text
}
}, mDuration);
```

Comment: all my text changing on same textview so that, and I am using switch case. each case has its new handler. handler gives an error. and sometimes text not changing or overtake. may be its wrong to use new handler in each case statements I am not sure.

Comment: @mehmet you miss the break statement in your switch **case 2** .. This may be problem.

Comment: @Ranjth the last line has break

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer for every second...

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 //put you code here 
                 //or set switch case for time 5,10,15 seconds
                }
            }, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
```

Comment: what is the main different between timer and handler.postDelay?

Comment: timer is auto re executes on specified time stamp, accept the answer if you get satisfied answer.

Comment: This is a bad idea for several reasons, including: 1) touching the UI from outside the main thread, 2) memory leak due to this never being cancelled.  It also doesn't really address the question asked, which has nothing to do with recurring tasks.  And finally, "set switch case for time 5,10,15 seconds" is unclear; what value are you switching on?